# How to make jquery code working in all browsers?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

```
$(function()
{
    var list = $('#ulGall li');
    currentItem = 0;

    function changeToSlide(index) 
    {
        var i = index;
        var nextImage = "url(" + $('#ulGall img' + ':eq(' + i +')').attr('src');
        $('#gall').css('background-image', nextImage);
    }

    $('#gRight').click(function() 
    {
        var i = currentItem;
        if ( i < (list.length - 1))
        {
            changeToSlide(i+1);
            currentItem += 1;
        } 
        else 
        {
            changeToSlide(0);
            currentItem = 0;   
        }

        $("#gInfo").hide();
    });

    changeToSlide(0); // this is the starting background of #gall
});
```

This code is on a separate file and it changes background image of #gall (click on #gRight)
It works perfectly in Firefoks, but not in IE8 and Chrome.
I have another jQuery functions in the same file and - they work in IE and Chrome.
Not tested in Opera and Safari.

How can I make this code to be `cross-browser`

Comment: You have an extra set of `});` at the end

Comment: what doesn't work (E.g. whatr error message do you get in dev. console or what's the unexpected result)?

Comment: If your code formatting was better you would have noticed the errors...

Comment: Without errors. Simply, the `#gall` is without background. No errors in Firebug

Comment: @Alegro, now you've edited away parts of your question which people have commented on. Please add back.

Comment: @LeeTaylor when some one comments on an error it's common to remove it. Why suggest to get an error reposted?

Comment: @RuneFS - So, in that case when a question is answered the question should be erased?! The question should be kept as is, otherwise the comments will end up confusing.

Comment: @Taylor usually edits is to remove narrow in the scope of the question. Would it be better if poster create a duplicate with the narrower scope? No delete what errors there might be that could confuse when some one points it out in a comment. Ppl being confused can simply compare whe nthe comment was made and when the last edit was made (or even look at the different version)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be missing the ending closing brace

```
"url(" + $('#ulGall img' + ':eq(' + i +')').attr('src') + ")"  ;
                                                           ^-- Missing
```

This might affect the way it works in `IE-8` as bad HTML might mess it up..

If the `HTML is not properly formed` then it might **not render** in the first place.

Also you have an extra closing parenthesis in the end.. `});`  .. Remove that as well

Comment: extra closing parenthesis removed - without result.

Comment: How about the missing `)` for the `url`

Comment: @Alegro .. Glad to have helped :)